# Select only of MIN values in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, min, rank

I want to select the earliest date and time from my data set and only show those row(s) that fit the requirement. And show 3 columns.

I got it to show the data in the right order by date and time. How can I just get it to show the data that have the mininum values? I tried using first, limit, and top x, but they don't work, and aren't exactly what I need since the answer may have more than 1 value.

Here is my example sql:

```
Select report, date, time
  From events
 order by date, time
```

Comment: What is the data type of `DATE` and `TIME`?  `DATE` is a reserved word so I assume that is not actually your column name.  If the column is defined as data type `DATE`, it will have a time component so I'm not sure why there would be a separate `TIME` column or how the two times are related.  For each report, do you want to pick the row with the minimum date and time?  Or do you want to globally pick the row with the minimum date and time?

Comment: I'm not using the word date and time. I just changed it to be simple. The date and times are not together. (Date and time are not in the standard format; they are listed as 1/1/2012 and military time 2212. I want to pick the row (s) with the mininum date and time for each report.

Comment: What is the data type of the two columns?  Are these `DATE` columns?  `VARCHAR2`?  `TIMESTAMP`?  Something else?

Comment: Both the date and time column are varchar2.

Comment: OK.  And the day portion, is that stored in MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY format?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 SELECT report, date, time
 FROM (SELECT report, date, time,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY report ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC) AS RowNum
       From events
      ) AS CTE 
 WHERE CTE.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: This code doesn't work at all. I'm getting an error at the first RowNum.

Comment: `rownum` is a pseudo column name, so you can't use it as an alias here; some other name (like `RN`) would work. You also can't use `AS` for the table alias in Oracle, so the fifth line would just be `) CTE`, though a name isn't really necessary at all in this case. And the ordering by `date` isn't be right because it's a `varchar`, so it would put Jan 1 2012 before Dec 31 2011.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing a bit as the data types aren't clear, but something like this might work (example using a CTE to generate dummy data):

```
with events as (
select 'report1' as report, '01/01/2012' as date_field, '0800' as time_field
    from dual
union all select 'report1', '01/01/2012', '0900' from dual
union all select 'report1', '01/02/2012', '0930' from dual
union all select 'report2', '01/01/2012', '0900' from dual
union all select 'report2', '01/01/2012', '0900' from dual
union all select 'report2', '01/01/2012', '1000' from dual
)
select report, date_field, time_field
from (
    select report, date_field, time_field,
        row_number() over (partition by report
            order by to_date(date_field, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), time_field) as rn
    from events
)
where rn = 1
order by report;

REPORT  DATE_FIELD TIME
------- ---------- ----
report1 01/01/2012 0800
report2 01/01/2012 0900
```

You may have a different date format mask; I've assumed US format as you referred to 'military time'.

Depending on how you want to treat ties, you'll want `rank` or `dense_rank` instead of `row_number`. See the documentation of [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions004.htm#sthref901) for more info. As Justin pointed out you probably want `rank`, which with the same data gives:

```
REPORT  DATE_FIELD TIME
------- ---------- ----
report1 01/01/2012 0800
report2 01/01/2012 0900
report2 01/01/2012 0900
```

The inner select adds an extra `rn` column that assigns a ranking to each result; each value of `report` will have at least one row that gets assigned `1` (if using `rank`, otherwise exactly one), and possibly rows with `2`, `3` etc. The one(s) with `1` will have the earliest date/time for that report. The outer query then filters to *only* show those ranked `1`, via the `where rn = 1` clause, hence only giving the data with the earliest date/time for each `report` - the rest is discarded.

Comment: Since it sounds like he wants to get multiple rows if there is a tie, I'd expect that he'd want the `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` analytic function rather than `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @Justin Cave - I missed he'd specified that; I just added my usual caveat, as I seem to default to `row_number`.

Comment: This is the only code that works so far, but I'm still getting the same result as my original SQL. It is showing all of the rows in the results, instead of just the mininum value(s). I am a "she" by the way.

Comment: @user1094628 - Sorry, no offence meant *8-) This should show one row per report; with rank it could show more than one. I've updated the answer with sample data and output. If that's not what you're getting, we must be missing something you've simplified or misunderstood what you want, in which case can you update the question to some actual sample data and what you want the output to be?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work assuming that every row has a validly formatted day and time component.

```
SELECT report,
       dt,
       time
  FROM (SELECT report,
               dt,
               time,
               rank() over (partition by report
                                order by to_date( dt || ' ' || time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24MI' ) asc) rnk
          FROM events)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

From a data model standpoint, however, you should always store dates in `DATE` columns rather than trying to store them in `VARCHAR2` columns.  Since you want date comparison and sorting semantics, you'll have to transform the data into a `DATE` which is costly at runtime.  And there is a great chance that someone will eventually store data in a different format in the column or store an invalid string (i.e. a day of '02/29/2011') which will cause your query to start generating errors.

Comment: +1 both for going straight for `rank`, and for saving me from typing a diatribe about not storing dates in `date` columns.

Comment: Next time, the date/time data will be stored in the correct format. This code just results in showing all of my results in the order that they were inside of the text file.